# tibia ot server walkable portal quest + timer and killing counter

Tags: lua

have this script, that im trying to this with. I need help with the quest system. Spawning the monsters works great. they should be linked together.

- when a player steps in a magic forcefield with the unique id "1000",
  quest start when entering the portal
  a timer starts of 5 min. also the player needs to kill 15 monsters.
  inside the quest area the monsters 2 monsters should spawn, and after you kill one, two more should spawn. (this works in my script)
  when a player kills a monster, a message will show progress
  both needs to be completed for the quest to complete, time needs to reach 5min and creature kills 15.
  on completion the player is teleported to position(1000, 1000, 7)
  if timer runs out and the player has not killed 15 monsters, the player is teleported to position(1000, 1000, 7)
  the player who has completed the quest will receive randomly a item in a array. the items are "2457", "2509", "2465", "2478", "2511"
  when the player has failed or succeeded the monsters should be reset to like on startup.

Here is the script below, any thoughts on how I can solve this?

````
local spawnPosition = Position(999, 974, 7) -- this is the monster spawn position
local monsterList = {
    "rat", "cave rat", "troll", "rotworm"
}
local requiredKills = 15
local completedPlayers = {} -- To track completed players

local creatureevent = CreatureEvent("SpawnRandomMonstersOnDeath")

function creatureevent.onDeath(creature, corpse, killer, mostDamageKiller, lastHitUnjustified, mostDamageUnjustified)
    for _ = 1, 2 do
        local rand = math.random(#monsterList)
        local monster = Game.createMonster(monsterList[rand], spawnPosition)
        monster:registerEvent("SpawnRandomMonstersOnDeath")
    end
    return true
end

creatureevent:register()

local globalevent = GlobalEvent("SpawnRandomMonstersOnStartup")

function globalevent.onStartup()
    for _ = 1, 2 do
        local rand = math.random(#monsterList)
        local monster = Game.createMonster(monsterList[rand], spawnPosition)
        monster:registerEvent("SpawnRandomMonstersOnDeath")
    end
    return true
end

globalevent:register()

local function resetMonsters()
    for _, creature in ipairs(spawnPosition:getCreatures()) do
        creature:remove()
    end
end

function onStepIn(creature, item, position, fromPosition)
print("Player stepped into the magic forcefield with ID 1000")
    if item:getId() == 1387 and not completedPlayers[creature:getName()] then
    print("Quest started for player:", creature:getName())
        creature:teleportTo(position(1000, 986, 7))
        creature:sendTextMessage(MESSAGE_EVENT_ADVANCE, "Quest started! You have 5 minutes to kill 15 monsters.")
        
        local kills = 0
        local timer = 5 * 60 -- 5 minutes in seconds
        local questTimer
        
        questTimer = function()
            if kills >= requiredKills then
                completedPlayers[creature:getName()] = true
                creature:teleportTo(position(1000, 1000, 7))
                local rewardItems = {"2457", "2509", "2465", "2478", "2511"}
                local rewardItem = rewardItems[math.random(#rewardItems)]
                creature:addItem(rewardItem, 1)
                creature:sendTextMessage(MESSAGE_EVENT_ADVANCE, "Congratulations! You've completed the quest and received a reward.")
            else
                if timer > 0 then
                    creature:sendTextMessage(MESSAGE_STATUS_WARNING, "Quest progress: " .. kills .. "/" .. requiredKills .. " monsters. Time left: " .. timer .. " seconds.")
                    timer = timer - 1
                    addEvent(questTimer, 1000)
                else
                    creature:teleportTo(position(1000, 1000, 7))
                    creature:sendTextMessage(MESSAGE_STATUS_WARNING, "Quest failed! You ran out of time.")
                end
            end
        end
        
        addEvent(questTimer, 1000)
    end
    return true
end```

i have tried to make the portal be linked with the quest area. when entering you should be able to start the quest. but that is not happening.
````